# Cannot override yii\web\JqueryAsset for asset/compress Yii2

Tags: php, jquery, yii2, compression, overriding

I'm trying to compress the CSS and JS in yii2 framework and it is working fine for me but I can't overrride the yii\web\JqueryAsset in asset bundle. I'm compressing the Asset component but one external jQuery library I want to load from cdn so how to override the JqueryAsset in bundle.

Here is my config file of compression.

```
Yii::setAlias('@webroot', __DIR__ . '/../web');
 Yii::setAlias('@web', '/');

return [
    // Adjust command/callback for JavaScript files compressing:
    'jsCompressor' => 'java -jar tool/compiler.jar --js {from} --js_output_file {to}',
    // Adjust command/callback for CSS files compressing:
    'cssCompressor' => 'java -jar tool/yuicompressor.jar --type css {from} -o {to}',
    // The list of asset bundles to compress:
    'bundles' => [
         'frontend\assets\main\SrpAsset',
         'frontend\assets\main\VdpAsset'
        // 'yii\web\YiiAsset',
        // 'yii\web\JqueryAsset',
    ],
    // Asset bundle for compression output:
    'targets' => [
        'srpDekho' => [
            'class' => 'yii\web\AssetBundle',
            'basePath' => '@webroot',
            'baseUrl' => '/',
            'js' => 'compress/srp-compressed.js',
            'css' => 'compress/srp-compressed.css',
            'depends' => [
                'frontend\assets\main\SrpAsset'
            ],
        ],
        'vdpDekho' => [
            'class' => 'yii\web\AssetBundle',
            'basePath' => '@webroot',
            'baseUrl' => '/',
            'js' => 'compress/vdp-compressed.js',
            'css' => 'compress/vdp-compressed.css',
            'depends' => [
                'frontend\assets\main\VdpAsset'
            ],
        ],
    ],
    // Asset manager configuration:
    'assetManager' => [
        'basePath' => __DIR__,
        'baseUrl' => '',
        'bundles' => [
            'yii\web\JqueryAsset' => [
               'sourcePath' => null,
               'basePath' => null,
               'js' => ['//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js']
            ]
        ]
    ],
];
```

And below command I'm using for compressing the assets .

```
./yii asset frontend/web/config.php common/config/assets_compressed.php
```

Everything works fine all js and css are compress but not external library. So, how can I override it in asset bundle.

```
//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js
```

Comment: please help how to handle this.

Comment: what do you actually trying to do , are you trying to compress a file from `cdn` link ?

Answer (score 1):

I have no problems with it.

Part of my compress config file:

```
    // Asset manager configuration:
'assetManager' => [
    'basePath' => '@webroot/assets',
    'baseUrl' => '@web/assets',
    'bundles' => [
        DateTimePickerAsset::class => [
            'js' => ['js/bootstrap-datetimepicker.js', 'js/locales/bootstrap-datetimepicker.ru.js']
        ],
        'yii\web\JqueryAsset' => [
            'sourcePath' => null,   // не опубликовывать комплект
            'js' => [
                '//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js',
            ]
        ],
    ]
],
```

[Sources and bundles from debug info](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vZ4Xe.png)

You can show more info here https://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/2.0/en/structure-assets#customizing-asset-bundles

Answer (score -1):

You can just download that link in your project

Comment: How does the OP do this?